# Missing Argument 1 Laravel 4 Controller function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

Okay, so a bit new to Laravel 4, and I am stuck on a problem.

I am using resource controllers on my routes, but I also have some other functions in my controller. As I said, I am new to Laravel, so I am not even sure that is proper practice.

So, my issue is, is that when I call the edit($id) function as a GET method, and then have the update($id) method as POST, it works fine.

Routes.php

```
Route::get('tasks/edit/{id}', 'TasksController@edit');
Route::post('tasks/edit', 'TasksController@update');
```

There routes that aren't working are:

```
Route::get('tasks/complete/{id}', 'TasksController@complete');
Route::post('tasks/complete', array('as' => 'tasks.completed', 'uses' =>'TasksController@completed')); //I've tried this route a few different ways
```

In my view, I'm calling the method with the Form::open() call like so:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('tasks.completed', $task->id))) }}
```

And in my TasksController.php my methods are:

```
/**
 * Complete the task
 *
 * @param int $id
 * @return Response
 */
 public function complete($id) //GET
 {

    //Find the task by id and allow to complete
    return View::make('tasks.complete')->with('task', Task::find($id));
 }

/**
 * Update the completion
 *
 * @param int $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function completed($id) //POST
{

    $tasks = Task::find($id);
    $tasks->complete = Task::completion(); //scope query from Model
    $tasks->save();

    //Redirect to main tasks list
    return Redirect::to('/');
}
```

No matter what I do, I get the continued error of: Missing Argument 1 for TasksController::completed().

I don't understand why the edit resource will work with no issues, yet the custom functions won't. I am almost positive I am overlooking something, but I just can't seem to figure out what.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to define the id parameter also in the POST route:

```
Route::post('tasks/complete/{id}', array('as' => 'tasks.completed', 'uses' =>'TasksController@completed'));
```

The difference in the form tag is subtle.

Without the ID on it it builds:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://site/tasks/complete?1" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

And with it:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://site/tasks/complete/1" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

But this is enough to the routing system not pass that parameter to your controller and then it's always missing.

Comment: Thanks Antonio! I knew it was something that I was overlooking. But why is it that I didn't have to use edit/{id} on the post?

Answer (score 0):

> Laravel default **POST** method used in form tag

and when used get method then defined

```
<form method="GET" action="http://site/tasks/complete/1" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```